# printstream & printwriter

Tags: java, printstream

how come System.out.println() method prints character on the screen when out is of type print stream which is used to display bytes

Comment: It's probably be best if you could elaborate on your question. I could approach answering this a number of ways and I'm not sure which way is appropriate. I also don't want to be accidentally offensive with my answer...

Answer (score 11):

[`PrintStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) was introduced in Java 1.0 and used in among others `System.out`. Later they realized that it was a major mistake to use platform default encoding to convert bytes to characters, so they introduced [`PrintWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) later with Java 1.1 which is able to accept an [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) wherein you can specify the character encoding. It was however too late then to change `System.out`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this piece of code (from `java.lang.System`) explains it:

```
FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
setOut0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));
```

It is creating a `FileOutputStream` to the standard out, and then wraps it in a `PrintStream`. `FileDescriptor.out` is "a handle to the standard output stream".

And it is converting bytes to characters using the platform default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

System.out is a special PrintStream, who's output is displayed on the console. Check [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`PrintStream` is a byte stream and `PrintWriter` is a character stream, but at the lowest level everything is byte oriented, I have read somewhere that each `PrintStream` incorporates an `OutputStreamWriter`, and it passes all characters through this writer to produce bytes for output.